# Hover and Scroll

Tags: scrolling

I used to have an app that would scroll the window your mouse was hovering over instead of scrolling the active window.  Unfortunately I lost that app. Does anyone know what that app is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use AutoHotKey for this:

```
EasyWheel(d)
; if _WHEELAUTOFOCUS if set, check which window is under the mouse and gives it focus if it hasn't already
; then send scroll event to the control under the mouse
; original code from Shimanov: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6772#54821
{
Global _WHEELACC
   , _WHEELMAXN
   , _WHEELAUTOFOCUS
Static t, s


   if ( A_TickCount > 500+t) {
      t := A_TickCount
      s :=0x780000
   }
   else if (s < _WHEELMAXN)
      s += _WHEELACC

   MouseGetPos x, y, hwnd
   h := DllCall("WindowFromPoint", "int", x, "int", y)
   if _WHEELAUTOFOCUS && (hwnd<>WinExist("A"))
      WinActivate, ahk_id %hwnd%
     testan:=WinActive("A")
    if (testan<>hwnd){
        SendMessage, 0x20A, d*s,(y<<16)|x,, ahk_id %h%
        }
        else if (d=-1){
        send {WheelDown}
        }else{
        send {WheelUp}
        }
}


WheelUp:: EasyWheel(1)
WheelDown:: EasyWheel(-1)
```

Comment: I adore it. I don't know what I'd do without it, apart from be massively less productive and have less fun.

Comment: Not what I the app I was looking for, but 10x better.  BTW, always love your comments on Lifehacker.

Comment: Thanks :)  That script is slightly edited from the version I took off the official forums, it sends an actual wheel-down message if the window is focussed. No real difference, but certain applications can handle things... differently, and that seemed to maximize compatibility with everything <3

Comment: @Phoshi, do you use this with a dual monitor setup?  It works... mostly.  I think the problems I see (with windows not scrolling when I expect them to) happen when the active window is on the second monitor.  (i.e. perhaps in the coordinate resolution?)  Still, great little script.  :)

Comment: I do indeed, works fine here. Is your secondary monitor left or right of your primary?

Comment: using volumouse also seems to break functionality.  I will have to find a script for that as well.

Comment: Ah, being an old Volumouse user, I can tell you that refreshing the script -should- fix it all. The `soundset` command in AHK can replace it, though. `soundset +5` puts system volume up 5 points, I'm sure you can extrapoltae from there :P Will need to be run in XP compatibility mode under vista, seems to have fixed itself under 7.

Comment: This script only works intermittantly for me. Sometimes it scrolls the window under the mouse, sometimes it scrolls the active window, and sometimes it doesn't scroll anything. katmouse works perfectly. Running Vista 32bit, dual monitors, primary monitor is on the left.

Comment: Don't appreciate the downvote much! :(
You say ketmouse works perfectly - did you have it on when you started the script? Or turned it on while testing? Because that will certainly interfere with the hotkeys.

Comment: Does not work in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3):

[katmouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) works well - small and easy to enable or disable from the system trayp

Comment: Works perfectly for me too, in Windows 7 64 bit. Unobtrusive and reliable little application :)

Answer (score 1):

There’s a few that can do that, but [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) for sure has that option (Mouse->X-Mouse).

Comment: Can you add the other ones? I'm looking for one that runs on Windows 7 (64 bits).

Answer (score 1):

I use [WizMouse](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/). Works in Vista and 7.

Answer (score 0):

[XMouse Toggle](http://factormystic.net/blog/xmouse-toggle) is a stand alone utility to do this on XP, Vista, 7 both 32 and 64 bit.

[image: XMouse Toggle]